# Possible to get metadata from Firestore snapshot Flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get `snapshot` metadata so can check if write to Firestore successful. I look at [source](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/a6a469a0da9e90b83d957c2c612a994ff1c73adc/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/snapshot_metadata.dart)  and see there is `SnapshotMetadata` and boolean `hasPendingWrites()`. But I cannot find how to implement. No open source dart project have used it.

Firebase [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-metadata-changes) say can use: `.onSnapshot` / `.addSnapshotListener`to specify `includeMetadataChanges: true`.

But I need to make sure I get metadata when making a query for `QuerySnapshot`. I am use `query` for `stream` not `addSnapshotListener`.

Like this:

```
        child: new FirestoreAnimatedList(
          query: Firestore.instance.collection('Collection')
              .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
              .snapshots(),
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          reverse: true,
          itemBuilder: (_, DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
              Animation<double> animation, int x) {
            return new Chat(
                snapshot: snapshot, animation: animation);
          },
        ),
```

I have try specify:

```
          query: Firestore.instance.collection('Collection')
              .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true),
```

But this not possible:

> error: The named parameter 'includeMetadataChanges' isn't defined.

I also try:

```
snapshot.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites()
```

But give error:

> error: The method 'getMetaData' isn't defined for the class
>   'DocumentSnapshot'.

Does anyone know how do this in Flutter? Is possible?

I try so long but cannot find how.. Help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## includeMetadataChanges Parameter Added

Support in Flutter for the `includeMetadataChanges` parameter was added in the **cloud_firestore** package at version **0.12.9**.

When you are calling your `snapshots()` function, you can now include it as a parameter.

This example returns a **Stream** of all documents in a collection, as a list of contacts. If `includeMetadataChanges` is **false** (default behavior) then the stream will not be updated when metadata changes (such as **hasPendingWrites** or **isFromCache**). If **true**, then the stream is updated by these changes.

```
Stream<List<Contact>> getAllContactsStream() {
    return Firestore.instance.collection('contacts')
    .orderBy('name', descending: false)
    .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true)
    .map((snapshot) => snapshot.documents.map((document) => Contact.fromFirestore(document)).toList())
}
```

With a single document snapshot, normal Firestore data is accessed with `document.data`. The metadata is accessed with `document.metadata`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [`DocumentSnapshot` class in FlutterFire](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) doesn't expose the metadata of the underlying document. I'd file a feature request for it on the [Flutter repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues).